# Store a base64 string in chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, base64, local-storage

Okay so I have a script in a Chrome extension that I'm building that grabs data, processes it, and stores it in [Chrome's storage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). Pretty standard stuff.

```
// a property of the incoming 'data' object is `base64`
// which contains the base64 string we are trying to save
chrome.storage.local.set({'data': data}, function(){
    console.log('Saved settings to localStorage!');
});
```

The issue is that a piece of the data object I'm trying to store is a base64 of an image. Attempting to store this results in a "QUOTA_BYTES" error, indicating that what I am trying to store is too big.

My next thought was to try and chunk the data off, via something like this:

```
chunkBase64 = function( base64 ){
  var a = base64.match(/.{1,4}/g),
      o = {};
  a.forEach(function(val,i){
    o[''+i] = val;
  });
  return o;
};
```

..which essentially just breaks it up into chunks and stores those chunks in an object that I then attempt to add to chrome.storage. This also fails.

I also tried using standard [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) just to store the base64, but this also does not work/fails because it is too large (?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [docs on `storage.local`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-local):

> `5,242,880`   `QUOTA_BYTES`
>   The maximum amount (in bytes) of data that can be stored in local storage, as measured by the JSON stringification of every value plus every key's length. **This value will be ignored if the extension has the `unlimitedStorage` permission.** Updates that would cause this limit to be exceeded fail immediately and set `runtime.lastError`.

Emphasis mine. You need to add `"unlimitedStorage"` to your permissions in the manifest.

Comment: WOW I feel so dumb. Yes, I can see that [in the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) thank you!

Comment: Happens to the best of us.